# Problema ao utilizar $_SESSION no PHP 7.1.10

Tags: php, session, php-7

Tenho dois servidores rodando o PHP, um na versão **5.4.45** e outro **7.1.10**.

Ao executar os arquivos abaixo na mesma url, apenas a versão mais antiga do PHP mostra os valores da Sessão "teste". Na versão **7.1.10** o Array é exibido vazio. 
Alguém já passou por este problema?

***teste1.php***

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['nome'] = 'teste';
```

***teste2.php***

```
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);

// 7.1.10 
// Array();


// 5.4.45
// Array ( [nome] => gabriel );
```

Comment: Na versão 7.1.10 aparece o quê ?

Comment: O array vazio, já na versão 5 aparece o array com "teste"

Comment: Aqui ta funfano -> http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8fd64022c78c90f8154b137aa4b719041eb98d38

Comment: Tem algo errado, como pode dar `gabriel` se  atribuiu `teste` na sessão?

Comment: @MagicHat aqui ta dando `teste` kk

Comment: @Francisco eu vi...hehe

Comment: Sugiro que apresente imagens da execução de ambas as versões, preferencialmente chamando `phpinfo()` no fim para ser possível de destingir diretamente cada uma.

Comment: A maioria desses erros é devido a sessão está configurada depois do Header HTML. Coloca todas as chamadas php antes de qualquer HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um bug relacionado à versão xampp, ou seja, x86 ou x64 bits.

"Eu tenho um sistema com x64 bit windows e eu instalei um xampp com php7, mas foi x86. Esta foi uma razão para esse erro, o apache falha.
Agora eu instalei separadamente apach2.4 (x64) e PHP7.0.1 que está funcionando perfeitamente agora."

Outros relatos do mesmo erro: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/547112-erro-de-session-no-php-7/

Possível solução:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path="C:\xampp\tmp"
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies=0
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

Um programador falou que existe um erro no php.ini.
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/php-7-session-start-not-working/211635/4